# How to join three table on different column using Criteria

Tags: hibernate, join

[image]

The above snapshot showing the relation, as I have required using Criteria.
I have three tables are Content(Id - PK, title), Article(Id - PK, articleId, sectionId) Section(Id - PK, title). **No Foreign key concept using in database.**

---

#### Content.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name="content")
public class Content{
  private int id;       //PK
  private String title;
  private Set<Article> article;
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
  @Column(name="id")
  public int getId(){
      return id;
  }      
  public void setId(int id){
      this.id = id;
  }
  @Column(name="title")
  public String getTitle(){
      return title;
  }
  public void setTitle(String title){
      this.title = title;
  }
  @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
  @JoinColumn(name="articleId")
  public Set<Article> getArticle(){
      return article;
  }
  public void setArticle(Set<Article> article){
      this.article=article;
  }
}
```

---

#### Article.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name="article")
public class Article{
  private int id;       //PK
  private int articleId;
  private int sectionId;
  private Set<Section> section;
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
  @Column(name="id")
  public int getId(){
      return id;
  }      
  public void setId(int id){
      this.id = id;
  }
  @Column(name="articleId")
  public int getArticleId(){
      return articleId;
  }
  public void setArticleId(int articleId){
      this.articleId = articleId;
  }
  @Column(name="sectionId")
  public int getSectionId(){
      return sectionId;
  }
  public void setSectionId(int sectionId){
      this.sectionId = sectionId;
  }
  @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
  @JoinColumn(name="id")
  public Set<Section> getSection(){
      return section;
  }
  public void setSection(Set<Section> section){
      this.section = section;
  }
}
```

Here I am using Criteria to join Content, Article & Section on basis of these column using criteria and these are

```
Criteria content = session.createCriteria(Content.class,"con");
con.createAlias("con.article", "ar");
con.createAlias("ar.section", "sec");
content.list();
```

Here what I am getting in result as:

> SELECT * FROM Content con inner join Article ar on con.id=ar.articleId INNER JOIN Section sec ON ar.id=sec.id

Which is not correct, If I match this to **expected SQL query as:**

#### Expected SQL query should be in this format

> SELECT * FROM Content con, Article ar, Section sec WHERE con.id=ar.articleId AND ar.sectionId=sec.id

Can anybody help me out this, how can I achieve the result using Criteria as same expected SQL query.

Answer (score 1):

```
// Firstly,you need entity to your Pojo like this:
// In Article, add a field: private Content content,support Getter and Setter for it
// In Section, add a field: private Article article,also Getter and Setter

// there have three Entity:content,article,section

// Create a DetachedCriteria for Section
DetachedCriteria sectionCriteria = DetachedCriteria
            .forClass(Section.class);

// Create a SubDetachedCriteria for Article InnerJoin Section
// the article is Section's field
DetachedCriteria articleCriteria = sectionCriteria .createCriteria("article",       DetachedCriteria.INNER_JOIN);

// Add join Restriction
// id is article's identity
// for this SQL:INNER JOIN Section sec ON ar.id=sec.id
articleCriteria.add(Restrictions.eq("id",section.id));

// Create a SubDetachedCriteria for Content InnerJoin Article
DetachedCriteria contentCriteria = articleCriteria.createCriteria("content",       DetachedCriteria.INNER_JOIN);

 // Add join Restriction
 // for this SQL:inner join Article ar on con.id=ar.articleId
contentCriteria.add(Restrictions.eq("id",article.articleId));

 // finally,after you finish the join,use the sectionCriteria to execute the CriteriaQuery
```

I wish it can help you,because I have used it in my projects

Comment: Hi MageSelios,

According to your answer posted here, the query will be print as:

[SELECT * FROM Content con inner join Article ar on con.id=ar.articleId INNER JOIN Section sec ON ar.id=sec.id]

But my expected query would be in this format

[SELECT * FROM Content content, Article article, Section section WHERE content.id=article.articleId AND article.sectionId=section.id]

[ID is the primary key in all three entity Content, Article, Section and there is no Foreign key concept in the database.]

Comment: Hi MageXellos,

Here you have told me to use DetachedCriteria but you know when we write this

    `DetachedCriteria articleCriteria = sectionCriteria .createCriteria("article", DetachedCriteria.INNER_JOIN);`

    The 2nd parameter use String not int, into createCriteria(String, String).

Comment: I have required the expected SQL query with this join

`SELECT * FROM Content con, Article ar, Section sec WHERE con.id=ar.articleId AND ar.sectionId=sec.id`